# custom event receiver in sharepoint-hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want create custom sharepoint-hosted app.
my aim: some like - help desk.

1. send ticket on email
2. and add this ticket on another list, on another site page.

app - event receiver (on added ticket)

list - event handler

how to create a custom event (example: on press button) in the app? sharepoint hosted app or sharepoint provider hosted app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might solve this with SharePoint designer and workflows. A workflow is capable of:

- Sending an email when a list item (ticket) is created
- Creating a list item somewhere else (this depends a little bit on where that somewhere is is, if it's possible.)